# ESXi VM lost after power failure

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

I have an ESXi host, which had a faulty PSU causing the host to randomly shut down. Now I am unable to import the VM. The VMDK file is gone and the VMX file is empty. How does this happen? the filesystem is not corrupted.
Do I have any chance of recovering the VM?

Comment: mmh this is abnormal, a brutal shutdown shouldn't remove the files unless a disk is broken (and you shouldn't need to import the VM, it should still be in the inventory). where was your VM stored ? on a local datastore ? with local disks ? can you see this datastore when you go to configuration > storage ? and can you see the VM in the inventory ? and are you sure that all disks are still UP and running ? (no broken RAID or other)

Comment: No RAID. I have the VMs on seperate SSDs. I can still see my datastrores, and the other VMs that were with the VM without a VMDK are fine.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Recover-VMDK-Data-Using-Vmware-Recovery-Tool This link might help, it describes the few approaches to recover a vmdk file.